# Circular progress bar is restarting

Tags: java, android, timer, android-progressbar

I have implemented a uptime with a circular progress bar. Problem is when i click start button time will start from 00:00 and progress bar also start but when it reaches to 01:00 progress bar will restart. I need a continue progress till 02:00 min.

```
private Runnable updateTimerMethod = new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            timeInMillies = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTime;
            finalTime = timeSwap + timeInMillies;

            int seconds = (int) (finalTime / 1000);
            int minutes = seconds / 60;
            seconds = seconds % 60;
            int milliseconds = (int) (finalTime % 1000);
            int barMax = 160;
            int barVal = ((int) (minutes) + (int) (seconds));
            mProgressBar.setProgress(barVal);
            mTvTime.setText("0" + minutes + ":" + String.format("%02d", seconds));
            myHandler.postDelayed(this, 0);


        }

    };
```

Comment: Try by changing statement mProgressBar.setProgress(barVal); to mProgressBar.setProgress(barVal/2);

Comment: Progress bar will move very slow if i give mProgressBar.setProgress(barVal/2);

Comment: Ok, It restarts still ?

Comment: yes It is restarting after 59:00

Comment: How Piku ? What was the problem ?